# Failed Uniformly Most Powerful Test

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

Suppose $X_1,...,X_n$ is a random sample from $N(\theta,1)$.
We want to test $H_0: \theta = \theta'$ vs $H_1: \theta \ne \theta'$.

I know that since there are 2 critical region for $H_1$, there is no UMPT for testing $H_0: \theta = \theta'$ vs $H_1: \theta \ne \theta'$

How do I find the best critical region for this hypotheses? What method can I use?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You can look for a UMP unbiased (UMPU) test.

Answer (score 1):

As per the fact that we are sampling from a Gaussian population, for this two-sided test there is a very simple procedure: the *"Confidence Interval Method"*

so you reject $H_0$ iff the Statistic Test $\bar{X}_n$ is out of the interval and, on the countrary, you will not reject it if the Statistic test is in.

So, as an example, you will not reject the Hypotesis that $\theta=\theta_0$ if and only if

$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]
{
\theta_0-\frac{z}{\sqrt{n}}\leq \bar{X}_n \leq \theta_0+\frac{z}{\sqrt{n}}
\qquad  
}
$$

Of course I set

$z=z_{(1-\frac{\alpha}{2})}  $